# Using setInfo() in C++ results in E_ADS_INVALID_USER_OBJECT

Tags: c++, windows, put

I am trying to use the **setInfo()** function in C++ to commit a few changes to a user's **e-mail** field in Windows AD. I am making a DLL that gets exported to a Windows service. But setInfo() keeps returning:

> E_ADS_INVALID_USER_OBJECT

Everything works fine if I compile the EXACT same code into an EXE and run it in a command line. But when the DLL is exported, and setInfo() is called, it returns the above error. This is a portion of my code:

```
IADsUser *pUser = NULL;
RESULT hr = CoInitialize(0);
VARIANT var;
hr = ADsGetObject(L"LDAP://CN=Foo Bar,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com", IID_IADsUser, (void**) &pUser);
//hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://CN=Foo Bar,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com", NULL, NULL, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, IID_IADsUser, (void**) &pUser);

VariantInit(&var);
V_BSTR(&var) = SysAllocString(L"foobar@email.com");
V_VT(&var) = VT_BSTR;
hr = pUser->Put(CComBSTR("mail"), var);
hr = pUser->SetInfo();
```

I am able to bind with LDAP successfully, the binding works also with this:

> ADsOpenObject()

When I add the domain Administrator credentials in ADsOpenObject, setInfo() works.. but I do not want to use username/password for this. Is there a way to use setInfo() in a DLL without providing the credentials in code?

Also, the IADsUser **Get** function works without providing domain admin's credentials. Is it a read/write issue? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I would test the differences between the DLL code invocation context, and the exe code invocation context. Are you perchance doing things in DLL initialization? In a thread attach? Is the DLL used in a program with different characteristics (e.g. not calling CoInitialize)? Etc. and so on, check the differences.

Comment: There is no initialization, there is one function that gets exported from the DLL. The DLL is run as different user (I think system). In the cmd I run the exe, it's exactly the same code, CoInitialize is used. Is it possible that system user doesn't have permissions to use the setInfo / write permissions? Because IADsUser::Get works without providing any Administrator credentials.

Comment: Do you mean configuring a user account in services.msc, using the 'Log On' tab there and selecting a different account for the service in question? I have tried to add another account there, like 'NETWORK SERVICE' but it's not shown there. Only Administrator, Guest and krbtgt are selectable. The service in question normally runs as 'Local System'.

Comment: @harry-johnston That helped! Thanks alot! I have added the computer account (with a $-sign at the end) to the AD Users&Computers domain container and the changes are now being comitted. This question is now answered. How do I designate your answer as the correct one btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't explicitly provide a username and password when you bind to the AD, Windows uses the security context of the process to log in.  For a service running as local system or as network service, this means that it logs in using the computer's AD account.

If you change the permissions within the AD to grant the necessary access to the computer account, it will work.  (The username for the computer account is the computer name with a dollar sign appended.)